# Rails 3, Selecting has_many (left Join)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

**models/host.rb**

```
class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :report, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

**models/report.rb**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :host
end
```

Now I want to select all Hosts with their reports, including Hosts that haven't got any report.

I tried to achieve this by

```
list=Host.all(:joins => "left join `reports` on reports.host_id=host.id")
```

but it seems like Rails only selects fields  from the `hosts` Table. So I am not able to access the report object with `list[0].report`.
In addition i would be much more happy doing the select without using raw SQL commands - in a more ruby-like manner.

How to get both, the host and the report in just one select and without using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
Host.eager_load(:reports)
```

Which will join the reports table and instantiated all the report objects. You can the use the loaded hosts and reports exactly as if they were being loaded on demand

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what i was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

> list = Host.joins("left join `reports` on reports.host_id=host.id")

this code doesn't generate report objects for you, only hosts.
But hosts objects now contins temporary attributes from report table
you can access them

> list[0][:column_name_from_reports_table]

Comment: That's what i also expected, unfortunately `list[0].inspect` only shows attributes from hosts table. The log also states that `SELECT hosts.* FROM…`was executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to select fields from other than **Host table**, you can always use `select method` to do so.

`Host.joins('left join reports on reports.host_id = hosts.id').select('reports.id, reports.column1, reports.column2, hosts.column1')` and so on and so forth.

This is one of the best features of rails, you can get your desired results in only One line, in many cases.